# set html link default action to run

Tags: html, google-chrome

We have a link to filename.exe on our website. We would like for the default action to be run (yes with it first asking the user if it's ok). A normal link does do that for IE. But for Chrome it always downloads.

Is there an attribute for the a node that tells the browser to ask the user if they want to run an app?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it's possible to do this as it depends on the browser default settings. I might be wrong tho...?